# drupal_http_request() with POST returns a 405 error

Tags: 7

I am trying to call an external API with a POST method which is working fine on Postman, but when trying to implement it in a custom module using `drupal_http_request()` I am getting a strange error.

> The requested resource does not support http method 'GET'.

This is the extracted cURL command from Postman: `curl --location --max-time 2000 --request POST 'https://example.com/api' --header 'Authorization: [token]' --header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' --data-urlencode 'subject=Lead XXX' --data-urlencode 'firstName=XXX' --data-urlencode 'lastName=XXX' --data-urlencode 'Email=test@test.test' --data-urlencode 'Mobile=XXX' --data-urlencode 'Interest=XXX ' --data-urlencode 'meetingdate=2020-04-20T13:00:00.000'`.

This is the code I am using.

```
$url = 'https://example.com/api';
$data = [
    'subject' => 'XXX',
    'firstName' => 'XXX',
    'lastName' => 'XXX',
    'Email' => 'test@test.test',
    'Mobile' => 'XXXX',
    'Interest' => 'Testing',
    'meetingdate' => '2020-04-20T13:00:00.000',
];
$options = [
    'method' => 'POST',
    'headers' => array(
        'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'Authorization' => [token],
    ),
    'data' => json_encode($data),
];
$request = drupal_http_request($url, $data);
```

I have the feeling this must be easy, but I couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong. I search the documentation, searched here with no luck.

Any hit will be appreciated.

Comment: For a start it doesn't look like you're doing anything with your $options variable. Shouldn't you be passing $options in your call `drupal_http_request($url, $options);`

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out... I was passing the $data instead of $options. Can't believe I stuck with this for hours. This is what happens when someone didn't get a good sleep.

Comment: No problem! Glad you got it sorted

Answer (score 1):

In your post request you have specified

```
'Content-Type' => 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
```

but your post data is in JSON format.

Perhaps you need

```
'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
```

alternatively, pass the raw $data array as the post data for key=value&key1=value2 form encoding.

You also need to pass the function parameter $options instead of $data

```
$request = drupal_http_request($url, $options);
```